# "In what age period" or "At what age(s)"

Tags: questions

Question:

> In what age period do people use the Internet?

Answer:

> 7 to 70 / between 7 and 70

Is that the right question for this answer? Or is there a better way to ask such a question?

Comment: I have problem with that interrogating structure, but I am sure that I will say ***"Internet users"*** For example, ***At what ages are internet users?***

Comment: Any particular reason for using "period"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In what age **range** do people use the Internet?
>
> From 7 to 70 years old.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound *okay* to me! Well...

I'd ask this way -

> *Which age group uses the Internet?*

It is

> 7-70 years

Comment: "_This does not sound okay to me_" But I've seen such a question in [Google books](https://www.google.com/#q=%22in+what+age+period%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: You might have read it somewhere...but I'd surely not prefer telling it that way! @Mori

Answer (score 1):

"Between what ages do people use the Internet?" is better if you want a numerical answer. "Age period" might result in people picking the age group that uses the Internet the most.